# Better syntax for if case, guard case, for case

Tags: swift, syntax, pattern-matching

Swift has the following syntax as a short-hand for a switch with only one case label:

```
   if case pattern = value { }
   guard case pattern = value { }
   for case pattern = value { }
```

I find this syntax confusing and poorly readable because:

1. The use of the assignment operator '=' implies assignment, whereas no real assignment is taking place (unless `case let` is used).
2. The order of the arguments is backwards: we are testing if value matches pattern, but we write it as "pattern is matched by value".

If the syntax looked something like this instead:

```
if value ~ pattern { }
```

then it would be enough to learn what the ~ operator does, and after that it would be very easy and natural to read.

(I understand that this is just my opinion and many people are happy with this syntax, but please bear with me here. Let's explore alternatives that are possible with Swift 3 or 4)

**My question is: is there any way to make the ~ syntax work for all cases where "if case" syntax works?**

Comment: This isn't possible because the patterns aren't first class citizens. There's no way to capture them as a parameter to a custom operator function. Plus patterns can bind new variables, and no Swift language constructs exist to allow a function to introduce new variables in the parent scope, and rightfully so

Comment: I see, thanks! That's a pity. Hope that Apple will come up with a better syntax in the next Swift versions.

Comment: I think reusing the `~=` would make sense. The equals operator is important because in most cases, pattern matching is used for binding variables, which is effectively assignment